# How to get the new database size after deferred drop operations?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We've been using the **sys.database_files** view and the **FILEPROPERTY** function to get the size of the database. Unfortunately, as I have just found in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx), the values returned by sys.database_files are not always reliable:

> When you drop or rebuild large
>   indexes, or drop or truncate large
>   tables, the Database Engine defers the
>   actual page deallocations, and their
>   associated locks, until after the
>   transaction commits. Deferred drop
>   operations do not release allocated
>   space immediately. Therefore, **the
>   values returned by sys.database_files
>   immediately after dropping or
>   truncating a large object may not
>   reflect the actual disk space
>   available**. For more information
>   about deferred allocations, see
>   [Dropping and Rebuilding Large Objects.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177495.aspx)

So, if a large table has just been dropped then when can I query the sys.database_files view reliably? How long shall I wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sys.allocation_units` DMV.

Whilst a deferred drop is pending the allocation unit will  still be showing [with a 0 value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx) in the `type` column.